# Why div is centered but not link?

Tags: html, css

In the below HTML, `div#entertainment-logo` has been centered. This only works now, and did not work initially, when the link within it was given the same `id`, but without the `div`. Why did this happen?

---

HTML code

```
<div id="entertainment-logo">
    <a href="/index.html" width="376px" height="82px">
        <img src="images/hdr-entertainment.gif" alt="CNN Entertainment">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#entertainment-logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 376px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `<div>` is centred by `margin: 0 auto;` only because it is a block element. This sort of aligning doesn't effect any alignment of children.

Anchors are inline elements and so are aligned by the parent's `text-align` property:

```
#entertainment-logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 376px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3oaq6Lf/)